# How to kick through time? Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I am creating a bot for a VIP channel, and I have a question. How can I implement a kick through time?

The bot has subscriptions for 1, 3, 12 months, how can I make the user get kicked from the group in a month?

Answer (score 0):

Make a database with users, their subscription plans, when they subscribed.
Then loop trough the database every day and `if (current_date > (when_they_subsribed + their_subscription_plan)): kick(user)`.
If you need any help in coding that then write to me on discord. RobertK#6151

Comment: add me to discord